# How to render an .aspx page into a modal in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need a way to open a modal in MVC with inside a WebForm .aspx page. 
I've tried to open the .aspx in a new window with JavaScript.

```
window.open("Test.aspx", "Test", "width=800, height=600");
```

It works, but for the design of my project I'd like to have it in a modal.

I thought to renderize the .aspx in the control and to pass the result string to JavaScript with an AJAX call...

But I don't know how to...

Comment: You can open the page in an `<iframe>` which sits in the modal.

Comment: @Sander i don't understand.. i have to do that from javascript? can i have an example?

Comment: No javascript needed other than the javascript to show the modal. Inside the modal container, put something like this: `<iframe src="/path/to/webformspage.aspx"></iframe>` https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=iframe

Comment: @luke88, @danludwig has added it. You can also style the `<iframe>` to make it fit in with your modal.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to render it as a partial with `@Html.Partial("Test")` (if using Razor). I am not sure though since we don't know more about the architecture of your app. For more info on partials: [MVC Partials](http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/MVC-Partial-Views.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're asking about. Just load the contents of the desired page via ajax and show it in a modal dialog using jquery.

Have a div on the page with ID "dialog", then add a script like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "WhateverPageTitleYouWant",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#ElementKickingThingsOff").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Test.aspx",
            success: function (pageContents) {
                $("#dialog").html(pageContents);
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can get more specific detail on the jquery used here:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  and here:
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: yesterday i thought that this solution was perfect for my scenario (i tryed with a basic .aspx )... but today i tryed with the .aspx that i need to use... in this .aspx i have a object tag referenced to a dll, and all the content of this object isn't rendered...

Comment: The ajax call simply does a GET on whatever address you specify, so this approach should still work once you figure out why your .aspx page isn't rendering correctly.  The two shouldn't be related.  If you supply more detail I can try to help.